# How can we have minOccurs="1" for a String?

Tags: java, wsdl, jaxb, cxf, code-first

I am using **Apache CXF** for Web service development . We have written Java code and  the WSDL will be automatically generated by the CXF Engine

I have a `String` named **xmlMessage**  which must have `minoccurs` set to `1` 
For this I used:

```
private String xmlMessage ; 

@XmlElement(name = "xmlMessage", required = true) 
public String getXmlMessage() 
{ 
    return xmlMessage; 
}
```

But when the WSDL File got generated , it still showed as

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xmlMessage" type="xs:string"/>
```

Please tell me how can i have minOccurs="1" for a Input Message .

Comment: use Regular Expressions and set the there 1 occurence

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug.
The sun api defines [required](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#required%28%29) as:

> Customize the element declaration to be required.
>
> If `required()` is `true`, then Javabean property is mapped to an XML schema element declaration with `minOccurs="1"`. `maxOccurs is "1"` for a
>   single valued property and `"unbounded"` for a multivalued property.
>
> If `required()` is `false`, then the Javabean property is mapped to XML Schema element declaration with `minOccurs="0"`. `maxOccurs is "1"`
>   for a single valued property and `"unbounded"` for a multivalued
>   property.
>
> Default: false

Might be [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3069), don't know if your version is a new one.